# How to deal with external project dependency and Gradle

Tags: gradle, build

This is not a simple jar dependency...

Basically I have 2 git projects, 1 project deals with data pipeline and eventually storing data to Solr. The other bassically reads Solr. Effectively this last project relies on 3 different projects that each have their own Solr collection.

Currently I manually clone the 4 repositories and launch the Solr instance with docker.

What's the best way not to do this manually and not have duplication using the 1 project?

Answer (score 1):

To run all projects not manually you can apply Docker Compose where you can configure dependencies between applications, to build all at once even in case of dedicated projects you can use [Composite Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/composite_builds.html).